# Wordbreak time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am studying myself (this is not a homework) and want to clarify why people saying the time complexity of this algorithm is O(n^2).
For String abcd example, this will do following computation

```
i=0, a
i=1, ab, a
i=2, abc, bc, c
i=3, abcd, bcd, cd, d
```

and the total operation is 10 a lot less than n^2 (16 where n=4)
Can someone please explain me why it's complexity is o(n^2)?

```
    public boolean wordBreak(String s, List<String> wordDict) {
        boolean[] dp = new boolean[s.length() + 1];
        dp[0] = true;
        for (int i = 1; i <= s.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (dp[j] && wordDict.contains(s.substring(j, i))) {
                    dp[i] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return dp[dp.length - 1];
    }
```

Comment: Even though the Inner loop is looped less than N time  Assume  its is n/2. So the total number of loop will be N X N/2 which is  (NXN)/2 so for time complexity we remove constants so hence its O(N2).

Comment: @RohitPadma You should add that as an answer

Comment: If you don't add that as an answer I will because it's _exactly_ what I was going to answer.

Comment: @PeterWone I will add the answer :)

Comment: @samgak - Sure i though its just a explaination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the Inner loop is looped less than N time Assume it is n/2. So the total number of loops will be N X N/2 which is (NXN)/2 so for time complexity we remove constants so hence its O(N^2).